# How to add regex to textfieldtablecell?

Tags: javafx

I have to add regex or pattern to `textfieldtablecell` with `textproperty` or another way like this code but this for a simple `textfield`

```
textfield.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     if (!newValue.matches("\\sa-zA-Z0-9*._ ")) {
         if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
            textfield.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\sa-zA-Z0-9 ._]", ""));
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: don't change a property in a listener to that property, for a textfield instead use a textformatter

Answer (score 3):

as kleopatra suggested, you should use a `TextFormatter` like:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
    String text = change.getControlNewText();
    if (text.length() == 0 || text.matches(MY_REGEX)) {
        return change;
    }
    return null;
}));
```

Notes:

1. length check required to let you clear the textfield(with Backspace)
2. `MY_REGEX` should be defined properly to mach every time you type a character.

   - for example if you have [A-Z]{2} it wont let you type **A**, but it lets you paste **AB** for example